# How does golang's garbage collector work when compiled?

Tags: go, compilation, garbage-collection

I'm trying to understand how does golang's garbage collector work when the golang code is compiled and I guess when using go run as well.  I figure go run is a little more straight forward and just runs the garbage collector along with the .go files you are running.  But is the garbage collector compiled into the binaries as well when compiling to an executable?

Comment: There is no difference in how `go run` works, other than it compiles, runs, and cleans up the binary for you.

Comment: So you're saying go run compiles it, runs it the removes the binary? and so to my main question, is the garbage collector compiled into the binary?

Comment: How else would it have a garbage collector if it wasn't compiled into the binary? (or at least linked in at runtime, though that's not currently available) A garbage collector can't really run as a separate process.

Comment: I never said another process, just running concurrently, so a thread.

Comment: A thread would need to be spawned from within the code, so again, it would need to be compiled into the binary in some way.

Comment: Yeah, that's been said.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The compiled object files do not contain any garbage collector "code".

When a program is run with `go run`, the `go` command will compile your sources, create and start an executable binary in a temp folder. See below.

When an application is compiled and linked into an executable binary, a go *runtime* is also included in the executable which is loaded when the binary is started. This runtime provides the garbage collector amongst other services such as runtime reflection and stacktrace information. This is the main reason why a simple Hello World application results in like a 2 MB executable binary.

Comment: For `linux/amd64`, `import runtime` is 1.1 MB and  `import runtime` plus `import fmt` is 2.4 MB.

Comment: @peterSO For `windows/amd64` the runtime is 0.99 MB, and with `fmt` included it is 2.36 MB.